# I want to download Ubuntu mobile os for android

Tags: android, downloads

I have dual core, 512 MB ram mobile device. Which Ubuntu OS can I install in my device?
Please give me download links to support my mobile configuration.

Comment: This needs a lot more information. What kind of Mobile device is it? Laptop, Netbook, Smartphone, Tablet? What type of CPU? 32-bit or 64-bit and is it even an Intel-compatible CPU? Do you have a CD-ROM drive? If so why not just downloading the Live-CD from the [Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) and see if it runs?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [XDA Developer Forums](http://www.xda-developers.com/) for Android specific questions. Search for your device there and you'll be able to see all the custom ROM's built for your phone.